# How to "remove" indexed pages in Google and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, nginx, seo, google-index

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web application. Some months ago I sent a sitemap.xml file to Google, so the urls are indexed.

Now, I would like to upload a new sitemap file with some updates on those URLs. I mean, the pages are the same but the urls have changed a little bit.

The moment Google index my new Urls, I guess It will have many urls with same duplicated code, right? I´m a bit worried because I have read Google penalizes this scenarios.

I have read a little bit about this, but I´m quite newbie with all this SEO stuff. So, it´s not 100% clear to me what should I do. The perfect for my would be Google could "remove" or forget somehow the old urls and index the new ones.

I have read about canonical urls and Redirect 301. Are these the right approaches? Which one should I use?

The rel canonical approach looks pretty clear to me. But, in case I should do a redirect 301, how do I do it in my nginx or AngularJS application?

**UPDATE:**
Just to provide a bit more detail:
These are the old urls indexed by Google: http://domain/en/boats/rental-sailboat-bavaria-palma-majorca-1

and these are the new urls I would like to index:
http://domain/en/boats/rental-sailboat-bavaria-cruiser-37-palma-majorca-1

Both of them returns the same content. Should I try to remove the old indexed url? Or both of them can be indexed?

Comment: You need 301 redirects > https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: Mmm right. But, the video redirects from one site to another site. That case, looks clear. But in my case, the urls change a little bit. Why should not use the rel canonical approach? Just to know...

Comment: "If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect. This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page has permanently moved to a new location."

Comment: " A rel=canonical link element is not the same as a 301 redirect,"

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-canonical-tag-vs-301-redirect-12611.html

Comment: In my case, old and new urls takes to same content. However, I just would like that Google remove the old url and index the new one.

Comment: Yes, so you need a 301 redirect. Not canonical tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The moment Google index my new Urls, I guess It will have many urls with same duplicated code, right? I´m a bit worried because I have read Google penalizes this scenarios.

No, Google does not penalize duplicate content. It is a hard to die myth perpetrated over and over on the Internet.

> I have read about canonical urls and Redirect 301. Are these the right approaches? Which one should I use? The rel canonical approach looks pretty clear to me.

If you application returns a `404 not found` (or 410) for the old pages, then no worry, Google will remove them one by one, even if it may take a bit of time. That's probably the best solution for you.

Else, if your application still returns content for the old URLs and if you can set a canonical link on those pages to the new URLs, then you don't need to implement 301 redirects. It is also a solution, but not the best one unless you have accumulated a lot of SEO benefits on the old URLs. In that case, canonical or implementing 301 would be the better solution.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds really good. My application will still returns content for the old URL, but as you say my old urls are quite new and don´t have any SEO benefits. So, in that scenario can I assume canonical is the best approach? And If Google doesn´t penalize to have two urls indexed that return the same content, can I do nothing? Just upload the new sitemap.xml and wait until Google index it?

Comment: Canonical or redirects are the best SEO options for you. If you don't care about SEO, doing nothing is OK too. Google will pick one URL over the other in search results (on the long run).

Comment: In my case I understand Canonical is the best.